# How to save directory tree in file with boost

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I want to save directory tree in file and after that to recovery the directory tree.
For that i need ordinary tree container for sub directories and files.I'm sure that this can be done without addition containers only with boost filesystem but i don't know how to do that only with boost

Comment: `tar` -- http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar ?

Comment: Thanks but i want to do that for my program library.Library must be multiplatform

Comment: While using the command `tar` might not be what you want, you might still want to consider using [tar files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29).

Comment: Now i'm trying to do what i want with tree class and boost file system but thanks for comments